# Returning Process Information From SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading

All, I have some complex C# code (Windows Forms) that is heavily embedded with calls to SQL Server (2008 R2 or higher is the assumed server version). As it stands. the code is serial and I have been asked to multithread it. This process of multithreading is now specifically associated with the expensive parts of the code, i.e. where the code does "Heavy Lifting". The majority of work is done with SQL Server queries.

I am just about to embark upon multithreading the main processor that deals with calls to SQL Server. I want to provide information to the user by-way of progress from the "SQL Thread" as the SQL procedures can be very long. I want to know if my method sounds reasonable or if there is a better way of doing it. My approach is as follows: (Note: the code below is just a small example I have built before attempting this with the actual code)

A. Start a `BackgroundWorker` thread from a button click event on the main form.

```
Bgw = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true, WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
Bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Bgw_DoWork);
Bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(Bgw_ProgressChanged);
Bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Bgw_RunWorkerCompleted);
Bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

B. From the `Bgw_DoWork` event, I launch my SQL method which is located in class `HeavyWork`.

```
void Bgw_DoWorkSQL(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Hw = new HeavyWork(this, ref Bgw, ref e);
    Hw.SQLProc();
    return;
}
```

C. Start another background thread from the `BackgroundWorker` (this time *not* `BackgroundWorker`), from within `Hw.SQLProc` in order to capture progress of SQL queries and to facilitate the cancelation of the SQL Server query.

```
// Globals.
private bool bConnOpen = false;
private SqlConnection conn = null;
private Form _MainForm; 
private BackgroundWorker _Bgw;
private DoWorkEventArgs _e;    

public void SQLProc()
{
    bool bConnOpen = false;
    const string strSqlConnMaster = "Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = RMH1006DHFinal; Integrated Security " + "= True; MultipleActiveResultSets = True; Connection Timeout = 0";

    const string strSQL = "DBCC CHECKDB"; // Expensive SQL Non-Query.

    try
    {
        // Create new SQL connection.
        conn = new SqlConnection(strSqlConnMaster);

        // Execute the SQL Non-Query.
        conn.Open();
        bConnOpen = true;

        // Start another thread to get user information and for cancellation purposes.
        Thread SQLThread = new Thread(myMethod); // This is not working.
        SQLThread.IsBackground = true;
        SQLThread.Start();           

        // Now run big query.
        _Bgw.ReportProgress(0, String.Format("Processing SQL Command '{0}'...", strSQL));
        ExecNonQuery(conn, strSQL);
        conn.Close();
        bConnOpen = false;

        return;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (bConnOpen)
            conn.Close();
    }
}
```

In summary I want to launch the expensive SQL query on a seperate `BackgroundWorker`. Within the method called on the `BackgroundWorker` thread (some query sent using an SQL connection, call it `SqlConnection conn`), launch another `Thread` which goes into another mathod using a seperate `SqlConnection connNew` which retreves the information about the major process on `conn`.

I would like to know is this a valid way of doing this? Also, if it is possible to launch new `Thread`s from a `BackGroundWorker` as the code above is not starting the `myMethod` method on the new thread?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to indicate progress, but can't because `ExecNonQuery` blocks.

As a matter of good practice, I would not use a BackgroundWorker for this if your db call might take more than say a second, as BW uses a thread pool thread. Instead, I would use a new Thread or, if you're on .NET 4.0, a Task with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`.

Back to your progress reporting: your db call blocks, so the only progress you can show is running or completed, so I would show some sort of marquee progress indicator. I would control this from the UI thread using a Timer - you don't really want to spin up a thread just to do an animation and you want to be on the UI thread anyway.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your reply. My idea was to launch the expensive SQL Query on a separate thread A using connection A, but also launch another thread B which uses a connection B to get the progress_completed value from SQL Server using `SELECT percent_complete FROM sys.dm_exec_requests WHERE session_id = {0}` where the session_id here can be determined from thread B using connection A. This raises the question; can you access SQL Server using two different connection simultaneously? Also, I am not sure I understand your statement about the BGW thread - this is the point of it, is it not?

Comment: @Killercam : The docs, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx, say this will only work for a limited set of SQL statements. AFAIK, there is no way to report the progress of a SQL statement while it is executing on the server. BGW was introduced in .NET 2.0 - I would avoid it in most cases now, especially if you are using the TPL.

Comment: I was aware of the limited use. Thanks. Are you saying that the `BackgroundWorker` should now not be used? I have Joesph Albahari's book *C# 4.0 In a Nutshell* he does not state any such problems when using `BackgroundWorker` for long running tasks. Is it not just the general-purpose implementation of the Event-Based Asynchronus pattern. Moreover, check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx) it statesBGW *can* and *should* be used for such purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to spin off a new Thread from your background thread, that's fine.  However, as you've stated, how you have it set up won't work in it's current state.

```
Thread SQLThread = new Thread(myMethod); // This is not working.
```

...should become...

```
Thread SQLThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myMethod));
...
```

...or simply...

```
Thread SQLThread = new Thread(()=>myMethod());
```

Comment: Hi George, thanks for your comment. I am now wondering why it is that `SQLThread.Start();` won't work in this case? I take it this is not the doing the same thing?

Comment: On the second example, `Thread()=>myMethod())` the delegate is declared and immediately spun off.  The first, with the ThreadStart, is simply declaring it, and it should still require a Thread.Start

Comment: George, thanks for your help. However, although the suggestions above were helpful they did not answer my question - in fact the code I had was doing the right thing but the priority was at its default level - this meant that the thread was not being invioked until the main SQL query was launched which was why I was not seeing it. Thanks again.